# '.map is not function' error when get data from api in react

Tags: reactjs

I 'm new in react and I want to render my products data that I fetch from api. I'm using the map function to show the data I get from the api on the screen. But the following error appears in the console .There is no problem with the data, I can see that it is drawn from the api as console result, but it does not print on the screen in the form of a table, I think it will probably work if I solve the .map function problem. What can be the problem .Have you ever faced this problem ?

**ERRORS**

```
ProductList.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: products.map is not a function
The above error occurred in the <ProductList> component:
```

**My ProductList**

```
import { ProductContext } from '../Contexts/ProductContext';
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import Product from './Product'

export default function ProductList() {

    const { products } = useContext(ProductContext);

    return (
        <>
            <div>


                <table className='table table-striped table-hover'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product ID</th>
                            <th>product is offerable</th>
                            <th>Product Name</th>
                            <th>Product Description</th>
                            <th>Product is sold</th>
                            <th>Category ID</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <div>
                        {products.map((product) => (

                            <tr>
                                <td>{product.productId}</td>
                                <td>{String(product.isOfferable)}</td>
                                <td>{product.productName}</td>
                                <td>{product.productDescription}</td>
                                <td>{String(product.isSold)}</td>
                                <td>{product.categoryName}</td>
                            </tr>

                        ))}
                    </div>


                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    )


}
```

**MY API DATA FROM POSTMAN**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "categoryId": 1,
            "productId": 1,
            "productName": "Bilgisayar",
            "categoryName": "Yazılım",
            "colorName": "gri",
            "price": 15000,
            "brandName": "ASUS",
            "isOfferable": false,
            "isSold": false
        },                         // example data. it continues like this
```

Comment: If the data which you provided at last is the one you receive then try `products.data.map(...)` .

Comment: i did but this time it gave this error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to iterate over the the object and not the array inside the object. You have to use `products.data.map(...)`. Also I would recommend optional chaining on your products object because you will try to access `.data` before  `products` is fully fetched from the server. Therefore your `products` object will be undefined at first and you can't access `.data` on it.

```
{products?.data.map((data) => ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `products.data.map()` instead
you skipped data which is the one containing the array